# get_permalink returning first letter

Tags: php, permalinks, templates, array

I'm trying to use an ajax function in my custom template to retrieve a post's custom fields to show a post overview. Getting the custom fields is working, but the getting the permalink isn't. I'm getting the permalink so I can link to the post. All I get back when I use `get_permalink()` is the first letter. Also, be noted that I'm using AJAX to return an array. I don't know if that is making the problem though.

Thank you so so so much.

Hunter

Code

```
function ajax_action_stuff()
{
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id']; // getting variables from ajax post

    $get_plane_custom = get_post_custom($post_id);

    $condition = $get_plane_custom['Condition'];
    $rules = $get_plane_custom['Flight Rules'];
    $manufacturer = $get_plane_custom['Manufacturer'];
    $model = $get_plane_custom['Model'];
    $price = $get_plane_custom['Price'];
    $lease = $get_plane_custom['To Lease'];
    $time = $get_plane_custom['Total Time'];
    $year = $get_plane_custom['Year'];
    $permalink = get_permalink($post_id);

    $plane_details = array("condition" => $condition, "rules" => $rules, "manufacturer" => $manufacturer, "model" => $model, "price" => $price, "lease" => $lease, "time" => $time, "year" => $year, "link" => $permalink);

    foreach($plane_details as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $value[0] . "|";
    }

    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of index 'link' of the array `$plane_details` is a string, and thus `$value[0]` gives you the first letter only.

Just replace `$value[0]` by `$value` and all should be fine.

Why are you referencing the value this way, anyway?

Comment: `$value` wasn't working at all. All it returned when I was handeling it with javascript was `Array`

Comment: Have you checked `$post_id`, `$get_plane_custom` and `$permalink` for their respective value? If there is everything working as expected until you set up the array, there is (normally) no way the echo is not working (as in you said you had no access to `$value`).

Comment: Also, I'm referencing the value because I'm making a way to grab the custom fields and show some quick facts about a post when you click on the post in the navigation bar.

Comment: Well ... glad I could be of some help. :) But why is it working 'now' - and not before? What did you change (in your code or mine)?

Comment: All I changed was from `$value[0]` to `$value`. For some reason, it worked now but not before. After it worked, I tried to experiment and just echoed out the json encoded `$plane_details` array without the `foreach`. That worked as well. I don't know sometimes. As you may know, sometimes code breaks and fixes itself for no reason. Either way, your solution worked perfectly. Even though I didn't use it, you still taught me something, which definitely is commendable.